# Jquery first click addClass selected second click removeClass selected

Tags: jquery, bind, unbind

I got 4 options and I want to be able to select more than one option or remove the selected class with the second click.

**Jquery**

```
$('.contact-method li a').click(function(e) {
        $('.contact-method li a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).parent('a').addClass('selected');
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

**html**

```
<ul class="contact-method">
<li class="sms"><a href="javascript:void(0);">SMS</a></li>
<li class="telephone"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Telephone</a></li>
<li class="email"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Email</a></li>
<li class="post"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Post</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Demo**
http://jsfiddle.net/XeELs/97/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of

```
    $('.contact-method li a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).parent('a').addClass('selected');
```

simply use

```
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to just toggle the selected class on the anchor nodes, try:

```
$('.contact-method li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();            
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XeELs/99/

Answer (score 0):

use toggleClass

```
$('.contact-method li a').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the toggleClass method.

```
$('.contact-method li a').click(function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XeELs/100/

http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/